# Invoking apache axis webservices using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, apache-axis, axis

I am newbie to web service. I got an Url(sample)("http://123.123.100.100/services") from a third party. They have assigned authentication to my IP address, from above Url I got the following message:

```
spm

Hi there, this is an AXIS service!
Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...
```

I tried in HTTP Soap request code using asp.net and got error as follows.

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

`Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`

I don't know how to proceed to call that web services correctly and also I have to know how to invoke the services they are providing?. Can anybody give some idea?

If you need more information. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you generate the SOAP request? Did you use the web services WSDL to generate a proxy service?

Comment: @KevinJunghans The service provider didn't provide any wsdl link. They just give(http://123.123.100.100/services) this link to access their webservice. Using   HttpWebRequest method to generate the soap request.

Comment: @KevinJunghans Without the wsdl link , how can i proceed for further process? Thanks for ur reply

Comment: Try getting the wsdl with this URL 123.123.100.100/services?WSDL

Comment: @KevinJunghans Thanks for your reply. There was some problem in my soap request. Now its working, no need for wsdl for this case.Thanks again.